# Haskell singletons: What do we gain with SNat

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-level-computation, singleton-type

I'm trying to grook Haskell singletons.

In the paper [Dependently Typed Programming with Singletons](http://cs.brynmawr.edu/~rae/papers/2012/singletons/paper.pdf) 
and in his blog post [singletons v0.9 Released!](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/tag/singletons/)
Richard Eisenberg defines the data type *Nat* which defines natural numbers with the peano axioms:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

By using the language extension *DataKinds* this data type is promoted to the type level.
The data constuctors *Zero* and *Succ* are promoted to the type constructors *'Zero* and *'Succ*.
With this we get for every Natural number a single and unique corresponding type on the type level. Eg for *3* we get *'Succ ( 'Succ ( 'Succ 'Zero))*.
So we have now Natural numbers as types.

He then defines on the value level the function *plus* and on the type level the type family *Plus*
to have the addition operation available. 
With the *promote* function/quasiqoter of the singletons library we can automatically
create the *Plus* type family from the *plus* function. So we can avoid writing the type family ourselfs.

So far so good!

With GADT syntax he also defines a data type *SNat*:

```
data SNat :: Nat -> * where
  SZero :: SNat Zero
  SSucc :: SNat n -> SNat (Succ n)
```

Basically he only wraps the *Nat* type into a *SNat* constructor.
Why is this necessary? What do we gain?
Are the data types *Nat* and *SNat* not isomorphic? Why is *SNat* a singleton, and why is *Nat* not
a singleton? In both cases every type is inhabited by one single value, the corresponding natural number.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

What do we gain? Hmm. The status of singletons is that of *awkward but currently necessary workaround*, and the sooner we can do away with them, the better.

Let me see if I can clarify the picture. We have a data type `Nat`:

```
data Nat = Zero | Suc Nat
```

(wars have been started over even more trivial issues than the number of 'c's in `Suc`)

The type `Nat` has run-time values which are indistinguishable at the type level. The Haskell type system currently has the *replacement* property, which means that in any well typed program, you may replace any well typed subexpression by an alternative subexpression with the same scope and type, and the program will continue to be well typed. For example, you can rewrite every occurrence of

```
if <b> then <t> else <e>
```

to

```
if <b> then <e> else <t>
```

and you can be sure that nothing will go wrong...with the outcome of checking your program's type.

The replacement property is an embarrassment. It's clear proof that your type system gives up at the very moment that meaning starts to matter.

Now, by being a data type for run-time values, `Nat` also becomes a type of type-level values `'Zero` and `'Suc`. The latter live only in Haskell's type language and have no run-time presence at all. Please note that although `'Zero` and `'Suc` exist at the type level, it is unhelpful to refer to them as "types" and the people who currently do that should desist. They do not have type `*` and can thus not *classify values* which is what types worthy of the name do.

There is no direct means of exchange between run-time and type-level `Nat`s, which can be a nuisance. The paradigmatic example concerns a key operation on *vectors*:

```
data Vec :: Nat -> * -> * where
  VNil   :: Vec 'Zero x
  VCons  :: x -> Vec n x -> Vec ('Suc n) x
```

We might like to compute a vector of copies of a given element (perhaps as part of an `Applicative` instance). It might look like a good idea to give the type

```
vec :: forall (n :: Nat) (x :: *). x -> Vec n x
```

but can that possibly work? In order to make `n` copies of something, we need to know `n` at run time: a program has to decide whether to deploy `VNil` and stop or to deploy `VCons` and keep going, and it needs some data to do that. A good clue is the `forall` quantifier, which is *parametric*: it indicates thats the quantified information is available only to types and is erased by run time.

Haskell currently enforces an entirely spurious coincidence between dependent quantification (what `forall` does) and erasure for run time. It does *not* support a dependent but not erased quantifier, which we often call `pi`. The type and implementation of `vec` should be something like

```
vec :: pi (n :: Nat) -> forall (x :: *). Vec n x
vec 'Zero    x = VNil
vec ('Suc n) x = VCons x (vec n x)
```

where arguments in `pi`-positions are written in the type language, but the data are available at run time.

So what do we do instead? We use singletons to capture indirectly what it means to be a *run-time copy of type-level data*.

```
data SNat :: Nat -> * where
  SZero :: SNat Zero
  SSuc  :: SNat n -> SNat (Suc n)
```

Now, `SZero` and `SSuc` make run-time data. `SNat` is not isomorphic to `Nat`: the former has type `Nat -> *`, while the latter has type `*`, so it is a type error to try to make them isomorphic. There are many run-time values in `Nat`, and the type system does not distinguish them; there is exactly one run-time value (worth speaking of) in each different `SNat n`, so the fact that the type system cannot distinguish them is beside the point. The point is that each `SNat n` is a different type for each different `n`, and that GADT pattern matching (where a pattern can be of a more specific instance of the GADT type it is known to be matching) can refine our knowledge of `n`.

We may now write

```
vec :: forall (n :: Nat). SNat n -> forall (x :: *). x -> Vec n x
vec SZero    x = VNil
vec (SSuc n) x = VCons x (vec n x)
```

Singletons allow us to bridge the gap between run time and type-level data, by exploiting the only form of run-time analysis that allows the refinement of type information. It's quite sensible to wonder if they're really necessary, and they presently are, only because that gap has not yet been eliminated.

Comment: Doesn't `TypeApplications` mostly or even completely alleviate this need? I hacked a quick example [here](http://ideone.com/vD4Gxp), though admittedly maybe I'm missing some limitation here. (Now that I'm thinking about it though, I can't really think of a way to do it without a type class like you did here)

Comment: @pigworker: Many thanks! You write: "although 'Zero and 'Suc exist at the type level, it is unhelpful to refer to them as 'types' and the people who currently do that should desist" How would you call 'Zero and 'Suc? I think good names are always helpful.

Comment: @Cubic What type class? And no, TypeApplications relates to *another* unrelated distinction: explicit versus implicit. That's an entirely separate distinction from type-level versus run-time. Google "Milner's Coincidence".

Comment: @Jogger I'd call 'Zero and 'Suc type-level value constructors. "Type-level expressions" may be a mouthful, but that's the price to pay for the bad decision to distinguish them from "expressions". "Typex" could become an acceptable substitute.

Comment: "They do not have type `*` and can thus not classify values which is what types worthy of the name do." Is there a self-inconsistency here, or does `*` classify values in some sense I am not aware of?

Comment: Things with type `*` classify values, and are thus the things worth calling "types". It is sensible to ask, since I have referred to `*` as a "type" what values it classifies. The answer is "types", which are one variety of type-level value. The fact that types are not currently available as run-time values (a) makes no difference to the validity of considering `*` to be a type, and (b) is a design error which should be rectified, allowing the deletion of `Data.Typeable`.